# How to link HTML5 form action to Controller ActionResult method in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a basic form for which I want to handle buttons inside the form by calling the `ActionResult` method in the View's associated `Controller` class. Here is the following HTML5 code for the form:

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>

<div>

    <h3>Login</h3>

    <form method="post" action= <!-- what goes here --> >
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
    </form>

</div>

<!-- more code ... -->
```

The corresponding `Controller` code is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string input, FormCollection collection)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case "Login":
            // do some stuff...
            break;
        case "Create Account"
            // do some other stuff...
            break;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

you make the use of the HTML Helper and have

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
    }
```

or use the Url helper

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" >
```

`Html.BeginForm` has several (13) overrides where you can specify more information, for example, a normal use when uploading files is using:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("myaction", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    < ... >
}
```

---

If you don't specify any arguments, the `Html.BeginForm()` will create a `POST` form that **points to your current controller and current action**. As an example, let's say you have a controller called `Posts` and an action called `Delete`

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   var model = db.GetPostById(id);
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var model = db.GetPostById(id);
    if(model != null) 
        db.DeletePost(id);

    return RedirectToView("Index");
}
```

and your html page would be something like:

```
<h2>Are you sure you want to delete?</h2>
<p>The Post named <strong>@Model.Title</strong> will be deleted.</p>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Post"/>
    <text>or</text>
    @Url.ActionLink("go to list", "Index")
}
```

Comment: I attempted method 2 with the URL helper, but I think the syntax I found was MVC3 specific and it did not work. This one suited my needs perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Dylan : Because there is missing ) bracket in Html.BeginForm line.

Comment: How did you have both `public ActionResult Delete(int id)` and `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)`? Isn't there a name collision between the two?

Comment: Thanks for a really complete answer explaining common overloads :)

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov the `[HttpPost]` above the action result lets razor know that the actionresult is the specified one for post. so it will know which one to take depending on the method used to call it

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm basically wrapping a button in a link. The advantage is that you can post to different action methods in the same form.

```
<a href="Controller/ActionMethod">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" />
</a>
```

Adding parameters:

```
<a href="Controller/ActionMethod?userName=ted">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" />
</a>
```

Adding parameters from a non-enumerated Model:

```
<a href="Controller/ActionMethod?userName=@Model.UserName">
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" />
</a>
```

You can do the same for an enumerated Model too. You would just have to reference a single entity first. Happy Coding!