# How do I update my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, sql-update

I have a webpage with a form, the form shows the information from the database but I have no clue how I can update the database. I have a saving method but I think it has to be an update method? I thought I should have some event handler on my button but I don't know how. I have searched Google now for 2 days but still can't find my way to fix it..

This is my form

```
@if (Model.Bestuur.Bestuursleden.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var i in Model.Bestuur.Bestuursleden)
                    {
                        <form role="form" action="" method="post" name="formEdit">

                            <h2>@string.Format("{0} {1}", i.Persoon.Voornaam, i.Persoon.Achternaam)</h2>
                            <br />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="vnaam">Voornaam</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnaam" name="vnaam" value="@i.Persoon.Voornaam" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="anaam">Achternaam</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="anaam" name="anaam" value="@i.Persoon.Achternaam" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="@i.Persoon.Email" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telnr">Telefoonnummer</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telnr" name="telnr" value="@i.Persoon.Telnr" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="informatie">Informatie</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="informatie" name="informatie" value="@i.Persoon.Informatie" style="resize:vertical">@i.Persoon.Informatie</textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="functie">Functie</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="functie" name="functie" value="@i.Funktie.Naam" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="btnSaveChanges" class="btn btn-primary">Wijzigen</button>
                        </form>
                        <br /><br /><br /><br />
                    }
                }
```

The button 'btnSaveChanges' is the udate button

My service

```
  public bool SavePersoon(PersoonModel persoon)
    {
        bool result = true;


        db.Persoon.AddOrUpdate(persoon.GetPoco());


        db.SaveChanges();
        return result;

        //Persoon p = new Persoon()
        //{
        //    ID = persoon.Id,
        //    FIRST_NAME = persoon.Voornaam,
        //    LAST_NAME = persoon.Achternaam,
        //    EMAILADRES = persoon.Email,
        //    CITY = persoon.Woonplaats,
        //    PHONENUMBER = persoon.Telnr,
        //    INFORMATION = persoon.Informatie
        //}



    }
```

And my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace WCFPlanningTool.Models.Bestuur
{
[DataContract]
public class BestuurModel
{
    [DataMember]
    List<BestuurLidModel> Bestuursleden { get; set; }

    public BestuurModel(List<BESTUURSLID> bestuursleden )
    {
        Bestuursleden = new List<BestuurLidModel>();

        foreach(BESTUURSLID bestuurslid in bestuursleden)
        {
            Bestuursleden.Add(new BestuurLidModel(bestuurslid));
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class BestuurLidModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public PersoonModel Persoon { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public FunktieModel Funktie { get; set; }

    public BestuurLidModel(BESTUURSLID bestuurslid)
    {
        Persoon = new PersoonModel(bestuurslid.Persoon);
        Funktie = new FunktieModel(bestuurslid.Functie);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class PersoonModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Woonplaats { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Telnr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Informatie { get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }


    public PersoonModel(Persoon persoon)
    {
        Voornaam = persoon.FIRST_NAME;
        Achternaam = persoon.LAST_NAME;
        Email = persoon.EMAILADRES;
        Woonplaats = persoon.CITY;
        Telnr = persoon.PHONENUMBER;
        Informatie = persoon.INFORMATION;
    }

    public Persoon GetPoco()
    {
        Persoon result = new Persoon();

        result.ID = Id;

        result.FIRST_NAME = Voornaam;
        result.LAST_NAME = Achternaam;
        result.INFORMATION = Informatie;
        result.PHONENUMBER = Telnr;
        result.CITY = Woonplaats;
        result.EMAILADRES = Email;
        result.DELETESTATUS = false;
        result.CREATED = DateTime.Now;
        result.CREATEDBY = Guid.Empty;
        result.MODIFIED = DateTime.Now;
        result.MODIFIEDBY = Guid.Empty;

        return result;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class FunktieModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    public FunktieModel(Functie functie)
    {
        Naam = functie.NAME;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting? explain in detail what your prblem is

Comment: I can't update my form, database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190929/how-to-link-html5-form-action-to-controller-actionresult-method-in-asp-net-mvc-4     check this link it may help you and if it did help then let me knw

Comment: But your action in your form is empty. How are you posting the form to your server?

Comment: @Dandy I don't really get it, I have everything in my service for starters and not in my controller.

Comment: you need actionresult for completing your task

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

It would call whatever public action method the form action is pointing to on your controller. You can then call save on the view model.

```
  [HttpPost]  
    public ActionResult  Save(MyViewModel model) {
    model.Save();            

    --- more code to do stuff here
}
```

Set your form action to MyController/Save

You can also use using `(Html.BeginForm`... in your code to point the form to a specific action method on a specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

You'r form is missing `using (@Html.BeginForm("myMethod", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`

please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124732/5600402